# Penalized GLM using the glmet - package

Tags: r, glmnet, multinomial

Since I have a lot of explanatory variables, I want to perform a penalized estimation of a multinomial logit model. Using the glmnet package, I would proceede as follows:

```
library(glmnet)
data(MultinomialExample)

cvfit=cv.glmnet(x, y, family="multinomial", type.multinomial = "grouped", parallel = TRUE)
plot(cvfit)
coef(cvfit, s = "lambda.min")
```

From other packages that perform the multinomial logit regression, I kow that the output K-1 coefficients for a dependent variable with K levels, since one of them is the so called reference category.

However, `coef(cvfit, s = "lambda.min")` gives me coefficients for each category, which confuses me:

```
$`1`
31 x 1 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
                       1
(Intercept)  0.015885341
V1           0.051848049
V2          -0.340036374
V3           0.421616900
....

$`2`
31 x 1 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
                       1
(Intercept) -0.017214370
V1          -0.329369991
V2          -0.145053512
V3          -0.160609561
.......

$`3`
31 x 1 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
                       1
(Intercept)  0.001329029
V1           0.277521942
.......
```

So basically:

1. Do you know how to interprete the output?
2. Do you know how I get the coefficients for category 2 & 3 - assuming that 1 is the reference category?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the answer by KH Kim [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/121155/glmnet-how-to-make-sense-of-multinomial-parameterization). His/her code shows how you can go between the output from glmnet and the more usual format from e.g. `multinom()` from `nnet`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! With KH Kim I could replicate the coeficcients as well as the probabilities. A question remains - event if it is not stated above - how to obtain summary statistics of the fitted glmnet output: standard error, t-statistic and p-values? In terms of interpretation - what do these coeficients represent?

Comment: I believe the package

Comment: I believe the package deliberately doesn't provide p-values etc - further explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12937331/why-is-it-inadvisable-to-get-statistical-summary-information-for-regression-coef/17725220. P.S. if my answer helped could you please accept it?

Comment: Many thanks for your help! The references cleared all my questions!